# Android Put animation in Page scroll in view pager using fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I want to put animation(zoom in-out,fade in-out,3d etc) when page scroll in view pager. my code is the following.

My first class:

```
  public class ViewPagerMainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
       OnClickListener, OnPageChangeListener {

  // all variable declare here
   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



      getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                );

     setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar);


    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_main);
    // other code here

  }

  private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

   public MyPagerAdapter(
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
  }

   @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {

    case 0:
        return FirstFragment.newInstance("");

    case 1:
        return SecondFragment.newInstance("");

    default:
        return SecondFragment.newInstance("Default");
    }
   }

    @Override
      public int getCount() {
            return 2; // return no of fragment created by us
      }
    }

    @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

       }

     @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

     @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

   @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
    @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {

}

  }
```

Second file:

```
        public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener {

  // all variable decalre here
     @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getActivity().setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar);
     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_lock_pager, container, false);

          // other code here
   return v;
  }

    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String text) {

      FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
      Bundle b = new Bundle();
      b.putString("msg", text);
      f.setArguments(b);

       return f;
   }

    @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     return false;
  }
```

Third file here:

```
       public class SecondFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

                    // all varible decalare here
           @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               getActivity().setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar);
               View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.password, container, false);

       // other code here
      // this method move to main pager 
    txtBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       ((ViewPagerMainActivity)getActivity()).pager.setCurrentItem(0);
          }
         });

        return v;
   }

    public static SecondFragment newInstance(String text) {

         SecondFragment f = new SecondFragment();
         Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);
        f.setArguments(b);
       return f;
       }

      @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
```

I want to put animation when pager scroll or call `((ViewPagerMainActivity)getActivity()).pager.setCurrentItem(0);` at that time  when pager scroll next page display with animation like zoomin-out please any one help me to how to do this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach PagerTransformer to ViewPager :

```
mViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
@Override
public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
    // do transformation here
    }
});
```

You can go through following links which will help you :

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer

http://andraskindler.com/blog/2013/create-viewpager-transitions-a-pagertransformer-example/