# Animation in Viewpager tab change fadein / fadeout as like Linkedin introduction screen

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, android-animation

I want to implement same kind of animation such as linked in does in android application for its Introduction(Login / register) screen.

I am using view pager for Introduction screen and i want to implement fadein fadeout animation on background image change, As per swipe right to left or vice versa.
I want to implement fadein and fadeout animation on background image change according to swipe of screen.
any help is appreciated.
Please take a look at my layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_skip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/skip_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Skip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.xyz.View.IntroductionScreen" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/connection_bt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="CONNEXION"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register_bt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="INSCRIPTION"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And View pager fragment layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/text_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tagline_tv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Laissez votre prochain job"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/details_tv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="vous trouver"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

sample Splashs creen this is what i want to implement.
[image: Linkedin Spalsh screen]
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Put animation in Page scroll in view pager using fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240774/android-put-animation-in-page-scroll-in-view-pager-using-fragment)

Comment: @Manish no its not about just fading background of view pager.. its a lot first i recommend you to check Updated linked in application Splash screen and than close this question.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is a `lag free` one and also handles the `Buttons`

[image]

Main Idea:

1) first create transparent background for your fragments.

2) Create `LayerDrawable` and add background image of each fragment as an item. Then add your `LayerDrawable` as a background of your viewpager.

3) in `onCreate` method set alpha of each layer correctly so just upper one has alpha value of 255.

4) set for each view of your `FragmentStatPagerAdapter` a tag that corresponds to drawable index that you declared in the `LayerDrawable`. for example when you open the app `FragmentA` is showing so its tag must correspond to upper drawable that is 2 (beginning from 0). last page tag must be 0 corresponds to lowest drawable.

5) change drawable of each view at the function `transformPage`

6) for adding the button use `RelativeLayout`.
In order to place buttons on top of all views use `RelativeLayout`. Later children are placing higher on the Z axis. You can see it in the code:

now lets see code:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager=null;
    int numberOfViewPagerChildren = 3;
    int lastIndexOfViewPagerChildren = numberOfViewPagerChildren - 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        final LayerDrawable background = (LayerDrawable) viewPager.getBackground();

        background.getDrawable(0).setAlpha(0); // this is the lowest drawable
        background.getDrawable(1).setAlpha(0);
        background.getDrawable(2).setAlpha(255); // this is the upper one 

        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

                int index = (Integer) view.getTag();
                Drawable currentDrawableInLayerDrawable;
                currentDrawableInLayerDrawable = background.getDrawable(index);

                if(position <= -1 || position >= 1) {
                    currentDrawableInLayerDrawable.setAlpha(0);
                } else if( position == 0 ) {
                    currentDrawableInLayerDrawable.setAlpha(255);
                } else { 
                    currentDrawableInLayerDrawable.setAlpha((int)(255 - Math.abs(position*255)));
                }

            }
        });


        }
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment=null;
            if(i==0)
            {
                fragment=new FragmentA();
            }
            if(i==1)
            {
                fragment=new FragmentB();
            }
            if(i==2)
            {
                fragment=new FragmentC();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return numberOfViewPagerChildren;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            if(object instanceof FragmentA){
                view.setTag(2);
            }
            if(object instanceof FragmentB){
                view.setTag(1);
            }
            if(object instanceof FragmentC){
                view.setTag(0);
            }
            return super.isViewFromObject(view, object);
        }        
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/layerdrawable" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dip" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:layout_margin="16dip"
            android:background="#2ec6e4"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Join us"
            android:background="#2ec6e4"
            android:layout_margin="16dip"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

LayerDrawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:id="@+id/Idofbg3"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/bg3" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:id="@+id/Idofbg2"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/bg2" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:id="@+id/Idofbg1"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/bg1" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

for lazy people who just do not want to declare fragments:

FragmentA

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container,false);

        return v;
    }
}
```

fragment_a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/FragmentA"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="This is Fragment A"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/textView"  
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its nice solution but my images are look like stretch one.. how can i use scaletype="cropcenter" or something like that property.
I tried  android:gravity="center"or "fill_verticle" but image look like stretch..any solution for that?

Comment: try `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: or your last friend is photo editing tools like `photoshop` or searching for free one or online one on the net.

Comment: nice one..let me check this

Comment: Really nice. However due to the multi-layer background, it's abit laggy when overscroll viewpager (Skipped 60 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread). I modify the viewpager source code to disable overscroll here: https://gist.github.com/hoavt-54/38d66fc9d975f78e95d6

Comment: @HoaVu I think your image resolution is very high !

Comment: i think this solution is bad for performance , possible OutOfMemoryErrors cause of large bitmaps

Comment: can it be done with timer and 3 dotted icons? like I donot want the page to scroll with touch but want a timer instead

Comment: what's the use of `lastIndexOfViewPagerChildren`

Answer (score 20):

Set a [ViewPager.PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html) to the `ViewPager` and achieve the desired animation using `aplha` and `translation` animation properties.

The most important input is the `position` parameter passed to `transformPage` callback. The position value indicates how the view is positioned currently.

Assuming the views in ViewPager are full width, here is how position value need to be interpreted.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
position | what does it mean
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0        | view is positioned in the center and fully visible to the user.
-1       | view is positioned in the left and not visible to the user. 
1        | view is positioned in the right and not visible to the user.
>-1 & <0 | view is being scrolled towards left and is partially visible.
>0 & <1  | view is being scrolled towards right and is partially visible.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

   mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            // Ensures the views overlap each other.
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

            // Alpha property is based on the view position.                    
            if(position <= -1.0F || position >= 1.0F) {
                view.setAlpha(0.0F);
            } else if( position == 0.0F ) {
                view.setAlpha(1.0F);
            } else { // position is between -1.0F & 0.0F OR 0.0F & 1.0F
                view.setAlpha(1.0F - Math.abs(position));
            }

            // TextView transformation
            view.findViewById(R.id.textView).setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * position);
        }
    });
```

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the screen record:

[image: Screen record]

Comment: The text works like an ordinary `viewpagwer` and the `background` `fades in` and `fades out`, I do not think your solution satisfying these two conditions. you simply have created the fade part but the text does not fade.

Comment: @Manish Nice answer but i want textview display right to left with fadein-fadeout animation as respect to swipe. plus background also fadein and fadeout but Buttons and logo keep as it is on screen.

Comment: @Swap-IOS-Android I've updated my answer. The text moves from right to left now.

Comment: @ManishMulimani Text works but what about background image..I will explain you my code, In my code i used view pager in which main view pager layout i added buttons and company logo(which is fix during view pager swip) and just text are added in view pager fragment and one more thing is that background image is in activity layout not in view pager fragment..I will update main question with code.

Comment: @ManishMulimani hey i used your code and did some modification on my layout(view pager match parent and put background image into fragment layout so it animation fadein -fadeout) and i get same effect that i want but animation lag while swiping. i tried hardware accelerated but won't work..any idea?

Comment: I believe you are using high resolution background image. You can load a scaled down version of bitmap as specified in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap). I tried with  `inSampleSize` of 4 with the android wallpapers. For `inSampleSize` 1 & 2, I get OutOfMemory error.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it will set the alpha for the entire view (background and content). The LinkedIn app only fades the background while the button alpha values remain untouched.

Comment: How can I effect the image fade, not on text, text should slide with opacity of 1?