# How can you animate within Android's TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-tablayout

I've implemented `TabLayout` with a `viewPager`, for four tabs.
The tabs have a `customView`, since there are two `textView`'s (text + unseen count) for each tab.
So, I'm able to handle a lot of UI stuff when changing tabs, but, I can't animate the unseen `textView`.

My custom XML has `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` for both the `textView` and its parent `RelativeLayout`.

Plus, I've tried setting this feature on the actual tab, tried a variation of animations, none works.
Ps - without animation, I'm just setting the visibility (gone, visible), which works.

```
private void updateUnseenOnTab(int position, int unseen) {
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0);

    ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(position);
    View view = vgTab.getChildAt(0);

    if (view != null && view.findViewById(R.id.tab_unseen) instanceof TextView) {
        final TextView unseenText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_unseen);
        if (unseen <= 0) {
            unseenText.setText("0");
            Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
            fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
            unseenText.setAnimation(fadeOut);
        } else {
            String currentText = unseenText.getText().toString();
            try {
                Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
                fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
                unseenText.setAnimation(fadeIn);
                unseenText.setText("" + ((TextUtils.isEmpty(currentText) ? 0 : unseen) + Integer.valueOf(currentText)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: @Markus - unfortunately not, animation doesn't seem to work that way with those views

Comment: The answer here might be helpfull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240774/android-put-animation-in-page-scroll-in-view-pager-using-fragment I manged to fade out, fade out the labels this way.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it out

Answer (score 2):

I don't know do you want to animate each tab or each child view inside tab. This will animate each tab one after another with 150ms delay. If you want to animate  each child  inside one tab just put it in another loop.

```
            tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabs.getChildAt(0);
            int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabsCount; i++)
            {
                int delay = (i * 150) + 750; //this is starting delay
                ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(i);
                vgTab.setScaleX(0f);
                vgTab.setScaleY(0f);

                vgTab.animate()
                        .scaleX(1f)
                        .scaleY(1f)
                        .setStartDelay(delay)
                        .setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator())
                        .setDuration(450)
                        .start();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good library for that:

https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms

This is developer documentation:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: This is not the issue here. You should read the question before answering. I was asking about animations on the tab itself.

Answer (score 1):

To animate views inside every individual tab, you can first set a custom view to each tab like this

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(R.layout.custom_view);
```

Now you can inflate each item in `custom_view` like this

```
View tabView = mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView();
TextViewPlus tabText = (TextViewPlus)tabView(R.id.tab_text);
tabText.setScaleX(1.5f);
```

Now you can call the animation when the tab is selected or on any other event.

Note that you might need to update to build tools v23 to use `getCustomView()`

Comment: will it work on lower android versions i.e kitkat , ics etc?