# How can i getCurrentView by position in a ViewPager?

Tags: android

I need getCurrentView by position in a ViewPager

This my ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class TutorialViewPagerAdapter extends ViewPagerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private View view;
    private List<Integer> views;

    public TutorialViewPagerAdapter(Activity act, List<Integer> views) {
        super(act, null);
        this.views = views;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int arg1, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return views.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

        int viewId = (Integer) views.get(position);
        this.view = mInflater.inflate(viewId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view);

        return view;

    }
}
```

And this is my activity

```
public class Tutorial extends FragmentActivity implements
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private List<Integer> views;
    private TutorialViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator;
    private int currentViewId;
    private View currentView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);

        init();

    }

    private void init() {
        views = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        views.add(R.layout.tutorial_step_one);
        views.add(R.layout.tutorial_step_two);
        views.add(R.layout.tutorial_step_three);
        views.add(R.layout.tutorial_step_four);
        views.add(R.layout.tutorial_step_five);

        viewPagerAdapter = new TutorialViewPagerAdapter(this, views);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.steps_view_pager);

        circlePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.steps_indicator);

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);

        circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
        circlePageIndicator.setCentered(true);
        circlePageIndicator.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        circlePageIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();
        circlePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        int currentPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        circlePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(currentPosition);
        enableStep(currentPosition);
    }

    private void enableStep(int currentPosition) {

        /*viewPagerAdapter.getItemPosition(object)      
        currentView = viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.getRootView());
        Log.d("DEBUG", currentView.toString() + " CURRENT VIEW");*/

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add all your created views in `instantiateItem` to an `ArrayList<View>` and then make a public method for getting a view from the ArrayList with `get(position)`. But be carefully, as soon the Activity is finished the views could be `null`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ViewPagerAdapter` you can use `FragmentPagerAdapter` which will have `getItem(int position)` method by using which you can easily access view.

You can take a look at this post : [Android Return back to same fragment after click on goto first fragment in view pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236331/android-return-back-to-same-fragment-after-click-on-goto-first-fragment-in-view/23236616#23236616)

Hope this help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's moot point. What exactly You need? Current view or view by position. Imho it is different things.
Current view:

```
currentView = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

Or view by index (you pass wrong parameter - should be int):

```
currentView = viewPager.getChildAt(currentPosition);
```